# Validar campo de una tabla en flask-appbuilder

Tags: python-3.x, flask

estoy probando flask-appbuilder, y hasta el momento con los ejemplos vengo bien. El  problema me surge, que no encontré (o no interpreté) en la documentación como hacer lo siguiente. Dentro de una tabla tengo definido un campo código, el cual debe recibir una cadena con la siguiente estructura 0000/00, el tema está, en que no sé como, ni donde debo hacer la validación, en otra aplicación con wtforms lo hago fácil, pero acá no se por donde ir. Desde ya muchas gracias, por la colaboración.

Answer (score 0):

comparto solución por si alguien está con mi misma duda. No sé si será la mejor opción, pero por lo menos cumplió mi necesidad.
En el archivo views.py definir vista de la siguiente manera:

from wtforms.validators import Regexp

```
class ClienteModelView(ModelView):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(Cliente)
    
    validators_columns = {
        'codigo':[Regexp('[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}', message='Formato Inválido 0000/00')]
    }
```

También muestro como tengo definida la tabla en models.py

```
class Cliente(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    codigo = Column(String(10), unique=True, nullable=False)
    nombre = Column(String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

Si alguien tiene alguna sugerencia, desde ya será bienvenida.
Saludos